# Drupal 7: how to show the main menu to anonymous users?

Tags: routes, users

I've installed drupal 7  with cartaro (its shares its login system with geoserver).

I created some pages and book entries: I choosed to display some pages in the main menu (I clicked on 'provide a menu link' when editing those pages).

The links shows in the main menu if I'm logged in, but they remain invisible for anonymous users. Where are the settings to force the main menu to be visible for anonymous users?

In Administration/People:permissions, I checked "View published content" for anonymous users.

---- Additional description following comments ----
Originally I had both Appearance/mytheme/ main menu toggled in "toggle display" AND a menu block added to the theme: menu visible only for logged user, not for anonymous.
If I toggle off the main menu in Appearance/toggle display of the menu theme: even the logged user can't see the menu.
I think therefore that only the main menu from the theme appearance actually shows up, the menu from strucutre/blocks won't show up in any case.

Comment: By default main menu IS visible to all users, but each item will have its own permission to get displayed on site.

Comment: In administration/Structure/Main menu, list links shows me the list of items making the menu. I do not see any permission on them. Is there another place to set ip up?

Comment: Does the anonymous user have "View published content" permission granted?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for mentionning, I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you have any node access modules installed?

Comment: nodes related modules: Field, Node, Nodetype access, Cartaro demo.

Comment: I would start by disabling the Nodetype access module and see if that fixes it after a cache clear. Also check the specific permissions like "view [type] nodes" that are provided by that module. It might just be that you haven't enabled those for the right roles yet

Comment: The main menu can be displayed two ways. The most common is to toggle the main menu for the theme display at _/admin/appearance/settings_ to put the main menu into a default region of the theme. The other is to disable the default, and to place a main menu block on the page. If you have done the latter, have you restricted access to the block by role?

Comment: Excellent comment: I done tests and corrected my post. I think my theme refuse to show the menu from structure/blocks/ and will show only the menu from appearance/settings for logged user --> should I edit something from the theme itself?